# Insert a private grails plugin to another private grails plugin

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I'm trying to insert a core plugin with the line:

```
grails.plugin.location.pluginCore = "../plugin/";
```

But a exception is throwing.

But when i use this in a normal project, no exception is throwed!

```
Compile error during compilation with javac.
/home/asapcode/Documents/svn/erede/plugin/src/java/br/com/qreserva/portal/pagamento/payPal/PagamentoPayPal.java:20: error: package org.hibernate.validator.util.privilegedactions does not exist
import org.hibernate.validator.util.privilegedactions.GetDeclaredField;
```

Any idea?

Thanks for replies!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem! But i not understand why its necessary.

This is the application.properties in the plugin A:

```
app.grails.version=2.2.3
app.name=PluginA
plugins.acegi=0.5.3.2
plugins.hibernate=2.2.3
plugins.i18n-templates=1.1.0.1
plugins.svn=1.0.1
```

BuildConfig of PluginA:

```
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.target.level = 1.6
//grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}-${appVersion}.war"

grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        // uncomment to disable ehcache
        // excludes 'ehcache'
    }
    log "warn" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    repositories {
        grailsCentral()
        // uncomment the below to enable remote dependency resolution
        // from public Maven repositories
        //mavenCentral()
        //mavenLocal()
        mavenRepo "http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org"
        mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
    }
    dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes eg.

        // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.5'
        compile('org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.5.2') {
            excludes "commons-logging", "xml-apis", "groovy"
        }
    }

    plugins {
        build(":tomcat:$grailsVersion",
              ":release:1.0.0") {
            export = false
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the (old) application.properties of plugin B:

```
app.grails.version=2.2.3
app.name=PluginB
```

BuildConfig (old) of plugin B:

```
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"

grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        // uncomment to disable ehcache
        // excludes 'ehcache'
    }
    log "warn" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    legacyResolve false // whether to do a secondary resolve on plugin installation, not advised and here for backwards compatibility
    repositories {
        grailsCentral()
        mavenCentral()
        // uncomment the below to enable remote dependency resolution
        // from public Maven repositories
        //mavenLocal()
        //mavenRepo "http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
    }
    dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes eg.

        // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.21'
    }

    plugins {
        build(":tomcat:$grailsVersion",
              ":release:2.2.1",
              ":rest-client-builder:1.0.3") {
            export = false
        }
    }
}
```

When I insert the dependencies of PluginA on PluginB (BuildConfig) and the plugins listed in application.properties it works fine.

I not understands why the plugin B when i insert the line

```
grails.plugin.location.pluginCore = "../plugin/";
```

in BuildConfig of plugin B the plugin not resolve this dependencies automatically.

But, thanks for the answers!